# Mod rewrite urls with

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm at my wits end here , I normally like to work things out on my own but this has me well and truly beaten here..
I'm trying to mod rewrite my urls that contain pluses...

/search.php?q=can+be+any+length

to

/can-be-any-length.html

Any help would be really appreciated becaus rewriting the + php is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite for this kind of work is not the best option as you can only replace a fixed amount of characters at at time. Using PHP would certainly be easier.

But you can use the ["N" (Next)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) flag to restart replacement, causing the rewrite engine to loop while there's a "+" in the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)q=([^&+]*)\+([^&+]*\+.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1q=%3-%4 [N]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)q=([^&+]*)\+([^&+]*)&*(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%3-%4.html?%1%5 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with RewriteMap :

```
RewriteMap mymap txt:/path/to/file.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ search.php?q=${mymap:$1}
```

Content of file /path/to/file.txt

```
- +
```

Comment: Does this work for you? As far as I know there are only five different map types defined: `txt`, `rnd`, `dbm`, `int`, and `prg`.